# Use of colon in do expressions in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am learning Elixir and I can't seem to understand the usage of `:`. Following three lines illustrate this:

```
iex(1)> quote do: 1 + 3
{:+, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel], [1, 3]}

# no `:` but now I need `end`
iex(2)> quote do 1 + 3  end
{:+, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel], [1, 3]}

# Oops! an error
iex(3)> quote do: 1+ 2 end
** (SyntaxError) iex:10:16: unexpected reserved word: end
```

What does `:` do here? And why do I get a sytanx error if I use `end` with `:` as in third input above?

There is a question about atoms and colon in Elixir
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089549/in-elixir-when-do-we-use-the-colon-before-or-after-the-atom-name), but it doesn't answer my question (at least to me).

Comment: I am assuming `:` is a shorthand for the interpreter to mean that 'until the end of this line' and is a shortcut to avoid writing end. In other words, `do ... end` can span across multiple lines, but `do: ...` cannot. Am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`do`-`end` blocks](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/syntax-reference.html#do-end-blocks) have special syntax.  The example from the syntax reference (slightly abbreviated) shows that

```
if true do
  this
end
```

gets converted to

```
if(true, do: (this))
```

In turn, the trailing `do: (this)` is the [keywords as last arguments](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/syntax-reference.html#keywords-as-last-arguments) syntax;  it is ordinary `key: expression` syntax.  So the `do:` (and `else:`, if present) keywords would get packed into a keyword list

```
if(true, [do: (this)])
if(true, [{:do, (this)}])
```

and from there [`Kernel.if/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#if/2) is a macro.

In your example, the same syntax applies, except that you're calling [`Kernel.SpecialForms.quote/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#quote/2).

In short, you either need both a `do` and an `end` with no colon, or you need `do:` and no `end`, but you can't have `do:` with a colon and also a trailing `end`.

Comment: While this answer is great already, I am to add that one should not muddle leading and trailing colons. Leading colons denote _atoms alone_ (`:foo`,) trailing ones denote _atoms **as** keys in a map or a keyword list_ (`[foo: 42]`.) Here it’s a keyword list, hence `do: this` has nothing to do with atoms at all, besides the fact that `:do` is also an atom itself.